# maven attach dependencies

Tags: maven

I create a simple maven `109` project - `maven-archetype-quickstart`.
 Then, add to `pom.xml` a dependency to derby.
When I run `mvn dependency:tree`, I see, that the dependency parsed correctly:
 `[INFO] \- org.apache.derby:derby:jar:10.8.1.2:compile`. 
But when I see the package generated by `mvn package`, it has only 3.2kB and the dependency is not there. Why? How it works?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because most people don't want all dependencies in their JAR by default. Imagine the people who want to use your artifact but a different version of derby.

To create an "ueber JAR" (i.e. a JAR which contains everything necessary to run it), use the [Maven assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html) (search for "Creating an Executable JAR").